# SignalR 1.0.1 slow first response on Windows 2008 R2 server/IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, signalr

I'm having trouble getting my small playground app to run smoothly on my VPS, the app runs smooth on development machine but once moved to the VPS every first request is takes ages to complete.

IIS does not have any specific configuration, the DNS is hosted on [DNS Simple](https://dnsimple.com).

I've assigned the appropriate app pool to the application and even changed the pool privilege to localSystem but that didn't affect the issue.

Here is my only hub class in the whole **MVC4** project:

```
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
        using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;


        namespace SignalR_chat.Models
        {
            [HubName("chatHub")]
            public class ChatHub : Hub
            {

                private static Dictionary<string, string> _userList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                public void AddText(string chatMessage)
                {
                    var validUser = _userList.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Key == Context.ConnectionId);
                    var message = validUser.Value == string.Empty ? null : 
    string.Format("<li><b>{0}</b>: {1} </li>", 
validUser.Value, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(chatMessage));
                    if (message != null)
                        Clients.All.retrieveInput(message);
                }

                public void AddInUserList(string nickName, string connectionId)
                {
                    _userList.Add(connectionId, nickName);
                    OnConnected();
                }

                public override Task OnDisconnected()
                {
                    var userInstance = _userList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == Context.ConnectionId);
                    if (userInstance.Value != string.Empty)
                        _userList.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
                    OnConnected();
                    return null;
                }

                public override Task OnConnected()
                {
                    var jsonObj = _userList.Count != -1
       ? new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_userList)
                                     : string.Empty;
                    if (jsonObj != string.Empty)
                        Clients.All.currentUsers(jsonObj);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is how the Hubs route registered in **Gloabl.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

And here is my jQuery code to handle signalr events

```
/* File Created: July 24, 2012 */

/// <reference path="jquery-2.0.0.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js" />
/// <reference path="shortcut.js" />
/// <reference path="bootbox.min.js" />


/**********************/
/*   Client functions */
/**********************/

var Chathub = $.connection.chatHub;

Chathub.client.retrieveInput = function (val) {
    $('.chatList').append(val);
    $(function () {
        var height = $('.chatBox')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('.chatBox').scrollTop(height);
    });
    $(function () {
        var height = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#chat').scrollTop(height);
    });
};

Chathub.client.currentUsers = function (list) {
    $('.userList').empty();
    var json = $.parseJSON(list);
    $.each(json, function (name, value) {
        $('.userList').append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
    });
};

/**********************/
/* Server functions   */
/**********************/

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    $('.chatInput').click(function () {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('nickName')) {
            $('.chatInput').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            window.bootbox.prompt('Enter nickname please', function (temp) {
                if (temp) {
                    if (temp.length <= 10) {
                        localStorage.setItem('nickName', temp);
                        Chathub.server.addInUserList(temp, $.connection.hub.id);
                        $('.chatInput').unbind();
                    } else {
                        window.bootbox.alert("nickname must be 10 characters or less");
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.chatInput').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            Chathub.server.addInUserList(localStorage.getItem('nickName'), $.connection.hub.id);
            $('.chatInput').unbind();
        }
    });

    $('.submitChat').click(function () {
        if ($('.chatInput').val() != '' && localStorage.getItem('nickName')) {
            Chathub.server.addText($('.chatInput').val());
            $('.chatInput').val('');
        }
    });

});

shortcut.add("Enter", function () {
    $('.submitChat').click();
});

$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
    if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting) {
        $('.chatBox').addClass("Tilt");
        $('.overlay').css('display', 'block');


    } else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
        $('.chatBox').removeClass("Tilt");
        $('.overlay').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Here is the complete [project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92237046/SignalR_chat.rar), as far as I know the connection in jQuery is being handled synchronously i.e. link events in .done()

Last point, I'm using bundling and minification only for JS libraries but not to include the "~/signalr/hubs" so that remains linked separately in layout view.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** forgot to mention that I'm using SignalR 1.0.1

**Edit2:** I've tried debugging the problem with fiddler however, I couldnt find any specific details. Only thing I noticed is that in every first request after removing all the sessions I get a response in 21 seconds but all requests after that get a response that is reasonably fast. Below are the stats from fiddler for a request after ending all sessions and a request before ending the session.

***New session stats***

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      332        (headers:332; body:0)
Bytes Received:  3,234      (headers:169; body:3,065)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    17:35:30.949
ClientBeginRequest: 17:35:30.949
GotRequestHeaders:  17:35:30.949
ClientDoneRequest:  17:35:30.949
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 21102ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    17:35:52.054
FiddlerBeginRequest:    17:35:52.054
ServerGotRequest:   17:35:52.054
ServerBeginResponse:    17:35:52.275
GotResponseHeaders: 17:35:52.275
ServerDoneResponse: 17:35:52.275
ClientBeginResponse:    17:35:52.275
ClientDoneResponse: 17:35:52.275

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:21.326

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
text/html: 3,065
~headers~: 169

REQUESTS PER HOST
--------------
[removing this one]


ESTIMATED WORLDWIDE PERFORMANCE
--------------
The following are VERY rough estimates of download times when hitting servers based in WA, USA.

US West Coast (Modem - 6KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (Modem)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (Modem)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s

US West Coast (DSL - 30KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (DSL)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (DSL)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s
```

***Stats before ending session***

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      332        (headers:332; body:0)
Bytes Received:  3,234      (headers:169; body:3,065)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    17:37:56.795
ClientBeginRequest: 17:37:56.795
GotRequestHeaders:  17:37:56.795
ClientDoneRequest:  17:37:56.795
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    17:35:52.054
FiddlerBeginRequest:    17:37:56.795
ServerGotRequest:   17:37:56.795
ServerBeginResponse:    17:37:56.899
GotResponseHeaders: 17:37:56.899
ServerDoneResponse: 17:37:56.899
ClientBeginResponse:    17:37:56.899
ClientDoneResponse: 17:37:56.899

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.103

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
text/html: 3,065
~headers~: 169

REQUESTS PER HOST
--------------
[removing this one]


ESTIMATED WORLDWIDE PERFORMANCE
--------------
The following are VERY rough estimates of download times when hitting servers based in WA, USA.

US West Coast (Modem - 6KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (Modem)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (Modem)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s

US West Coast (DSL - 30KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (DSL)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (DSL)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s
```

***Edit3:*** I've noticed the following output in VS.

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.ComponentModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Activities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c514b873\93518333\App_Web_lcqvz5d1.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c514b873\93518333\App_Web_l5dllaun.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x275c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1f80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1878) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2238) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x69c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x21d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xadc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1278) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x177c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1e90) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1988) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x56c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1100) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x22c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7720] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7720] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Apparently there are some exceptions in some of the tasks. not sure if it's my code though or some other issue

Comment: Can it be that there is a buffering proxy (or load balancer, or any other piece of networking hardware) between you and the server? SignalR will try forever frame (or server sent events) transports first and then it will fallback to longpolling. If "it takes forever" means around 5-10 seconds, then this might be it. You can run any networking sniffing tool (e.g. www.fiddler2.com) to check. If you use fiddler, then don't forget to turn on the streaming mode, otherwise fiddler itself would buffer the response.

Comment: That's the only thing I'm suspecting right now, that something from my dns hosting or vps is creating this issue. I'll try fiddle and update this thread later. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the thread, apparently it's doing what you said except that the first response takes always a littler over 20 seconds. is there anything specific I should be looking at in fiddler? I've had the streaming mode on btw.